# window.open behaves differently in Chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome, internet-explorer

Let's say I have the following file hierarchy-

```
 / ProjectRoot
  / ChildFolder1
  / ChildFolder2
     - Child2_page1.aspx
     - Child2_page2.aspx
```

I'm now at page **Child2_page1.aspx**, and I have the following code

```
var url = "Child2_page2.aspx";
window.open(url);
```

In IE, http://projectroot/childfolder2/child2_page2.aspx will be called.

However,

In Chrome, http://projectroot/child2_page2.aspx will be called.

Why are they behaving differently?

Is there anyway to make Chrome behaves like IE without changing the URL? Changing the URL will be a big impact for my application :(

Comment: I don't think `window.open('url')` behave different in different browsers. They may be different if you are opening at different folder hierarchy. Are you opening the page from the same location in both the browsers.

Comment: yes I am sure Im opening the page from same location for both browser. I opened the same page side by side.